# AngularFirebase 2 - AngularFireAuth signout not signing the user out

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am creating a simple login using angular-firebase and is using email password as the authentication method for that. But even after caaling the af.auth.signout() method, the user is not null and is still logged in while I reload the page.

Please the code snippet below:

```
constructor(public af: AngularFireAuth,private router: Router) {
         this.af.authState.subscribe(auth => { 
         if (auth != null) {
          this.authenticated = true;
         }
        }
      )
     }

      login() { 
        this.af.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("email","password");
        this.authenticated = true;
      }

    logOut() {
      this.af.auth.signOut();
      this.authenticated = false;
    }
```

So when I call login(), the user was initially null and is logged in. But when the logOut() method is called, the method executes successfully but while the constructor is called the firebase.user(auth in my code snippet) is not null and so this.authenticated will still be true and user is logged in.

Why is the logOut() method (this.af.auth.signOut()) not making the user null and signed out?

Comment: what is the default value of `this.authenticated`. and how you figure out logout was success?

Comment: this.authenticated is false by default and even after calling the logOut() method, on refreshing the page the user is still signedin.
Another issue is it is taking more than 20 seconds to successfully log the user in using auth.SignIn() method.

Comment: `logOut()` method returns a promise. do `logOut().then().catch()` to get any error messages eg: `.signOut().catch(err=> console.log(err)`

Answer (score 1):

you need to unsubscribe the observable otherwise memory leak will happen

```
private sub: any;
   constructor(public af: AngularFireAuth,private router: Router) {
     this.sub =this.af.authState.subscribe(auth => { 
     if (auth != null) {
      this.authenticated = true;
     }
    }
  )
 }


logOut() {
  this.af.auth.signOut();
  this.authenticated = false;
}
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? How will memory leak happen if we sign out? And what is "this.sub"???

Comment: you are subscribing the observable and storing the observable into the sub variable so that you can unsubscribe and avoid memory leak

Answer (score -1):

The signOut() returns a promise, so you better write:

```
logOut() {
  this.fb.auth.signOut()
    .then(() => {
      this.authenticated = false;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```